# appendRow not working when appending to a filtered range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a script that is supposed to append a row to a filtered range within a Google Sheets. My script works in normal situation. But when the last row of the destination range is deleted AND the range is filtered on one of the fields (image below illustrates the situation), the appendRow does not work.

Screenshot of the situations where appendRow does/doesn't work:

[[image: spreadsheet samples]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PA7ek.png)

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
  outputRowArray = [1,2];
  destinationUrl = "XXX";
  destinationSheet = "Sheet1"

  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destinationUrl).getSheetByName(destinationSheet).appendRow(outputRowArray);  
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `the appendRow does not work.`?

Comment: It just doesn't append anything. The script runs successfully and no error is displayed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `It just doesn't append anything.`. In my environment, when the sheet is correct, `[1,2]` is appended to the next row of the last row of the sheet. I think that this situation is the same with [Rubén's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62463282/7108653). So can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that `appendRow` appends a row to the sheet, that means that the row is added after the last row with data in sheet. Also you are missing that the filter boundaries are only updated when inserting a row/column that are part of the filter range (this should be done **between** two rows/columns) but not when appending them (inserting the row/column after the last row/column of the filter range)

On the past I have seeing similar questions claiming that appendRows don't work but what was happening is that the sheet include some values (sometimes an empty string) several rows below of the rows shows in the screen.

To help you to understand what is happening log some sheets characteristics by using [Class Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) methods like

- `getLastRow()`
- `getMaxRows()`

To log things you could use `Logger.log(something)` and `console.log(something)`. for further details checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting

Something else to try is to log the last row after appending a new row, but bear in mind that you might need to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` first. Example:

```
function myFunction() {
  outputRowArray = [1,2];
  destinationUrl = "XXX";
  destinationSheet = "Sheet1"

  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destinationUrl).getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
  sheet.appendRow(outputRowArray);  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  console.info(lastRow);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. So I expect that the appendRow adds a row to the sheet, and it does in usual cases. But in the situation that I mentioned (filtered range), it just does nothing. No data are added anywhere in the sheet. And no error is displayed.

Comment: same for me. I logged the last row, and used flush as suggested but append didn't add the data or change the last row.

Comment: @AssafLivne I suggest you to post a new question as the OP is not clear according to [Tanaike's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461107/appendrow-not-working-when-appending-to-a-filtered-range-in-google-sheets/62463282#comment110480299_62461107)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70499093/appendrow-function-doesnt-work-when-the-google-sheet-is-filtered

Answer (score 0):

More than a work around then a solution.

```
function myFunction() {
  outputRowArray = [1,2];
  destinationUrl = "XXX";
  destinationSheet = "Sheet1"

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destinationUrl).getSheetByName(destinationSheet)
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow()
  var insert_range = sheet.getRange(last_row+1,1,1,outputRowArray.length()) // not really sure that I got right the dims
  insert_range.setValues([outputRowArray])
}
```

Comment: `last_row` was not declared